# Peer Object Communication in C++

Tags: c++

[image: Object peers]

Have to design a infra which establish the communication between peer objects.
Here all managers are peers and nobody knows each other. Manager subscribe for the event and other manager publishes. A manager doesnt have reference of other managers and they only publish and subscribe. Director only creates those manager.

Any suggestion for designing such infra which enables the managers to send event to other??

Comment: Try with Boost.Signals

Answer (score 0):

http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.htm

Look into the observer pattern. If you have problems applying it to your problem let me know and I'll guide you on the right path.

Comment: Observer pattern will help to communicate to manager to director. But I need the communication between peers which dont know about each other.

Answer (score 0):

Boost.Signals2 solution:

```
#include <boost/signals2/signal.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

class Manager{
public:
    signals2::signal<void ()>    *Msg;
    void Foo() { cout << "Foo" << endl;}    
};

class Director{
public:
    Manager CreateManager() { return Manager();}
};

int main()
{
    Director dir;
    Manager m1 = dir.CreateManager();
    Manager m2 = dir.CreateManager();

    m1.Msg = new signals2::signal<void ()>();
    m1.Msg->connect(bind(&Manager::Foo, &m2));
    (*m1.Msg)();
}
```

Comment: @cpp..unfortunately we dont have provision to use Boost library as per business rules..

Comment: Also, I see managers directly connected to other managers. What's the win here?